# C++ Workplace and compiler. Hello World testing for beginner

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am beginning to learn C++ after ages of not programming in any language (last thing I did were a few lines in Python). I know a little bit about programming, object oriented programming, but all theoretical. Not in any particular programming language.

I am following a few books about the language itself but I don't know where to test a few lines of code.

What could be a convenient workplace to do this? I tried installing Visual Studio but it isn't straightforward for me to see how to (or where in it to) write/compile and run small pieces of code.

Perhaps there are simpler environments that are more convenient for just beginning learning the language.

What simpler working environments can I use?

Is Visual Studio a good choice for beginning (testing my first lines of code in C++) and I just should study more how it works?

Comment: There are also plenty of [online C++ compilers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator) that are really useful for starting out and let you try several different compilers and versions.

Comment: Yes it is good. And also `g++`

Comment: Maybe you should try to use a simple editor and a compiler by hand. It will not harm at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest environment I found for starting to develop in C or C++ is Code::Blocks:

[www.codeblocks.org](http://www.codeblocks.org)

Or, directly, the download link with everything you need:

http://prdownload.berlios.de/codeblocks/codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe

In there, just do "new Project", select "Console application", then "C++", and it will creates an "Hello World" Project for you.

Although Visual Studio is very good, the huge numbers of features immediately available can be intimidating for the beginner.

Comment: Question: Should I select C or C++? The two options appear. I am trying to learn C++, but maybe you said C on purpose.

Comment: I put C++. I got it working.

Comment: @ABC: Didn't see you wanted C++, sorry. But yes, of course, if you want to program in C++, use C++. I edited my answer.
Also, if this helped you, please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer visual studio IDE any day.  And you have it available with you. It could be learning initially but worth it.

If you have questions / doubts about it some one here will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just drop into [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com) and play around in there. No installation or set-up required, and immediate feedback on your snippets.

Alternatively, if you're on IRC, head to Freenode and send snippets to [geordi prime](http://www.eelis.net/geordi/).

Answer (score 0):

I started with Dev-C++. It is a IDE which makes it easier.

Even if you don't know hello world in c++ or C you can make a new project at the top left and click on Console Application. Dev-C++ has a C++ tutorial which makes it a lot easier.

But I also suggest Microsoft Visual Studio for Windows 7 and up.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and hand compile your sources with the compiler (VC++ or MinGW). It'd give you a lot of exposure on understanding build scripts which you'd later require for doing something serious. As for the compiler, I'd recommend MinGW since it's (almost) complete in its support for C++11; use a pre-packaged binary setup like [TDM GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download).